# AngularJS - ng-options compound text of option

Tags: angularjs

I have array with object:

```
[
    ...
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Value',
        desc: 'Test'
    }      
    ...  
]
```

How i can generate option by ng-options with text `Value (Test)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```xml
<select
    ng-model="selectedOption"
    ng-options="o.id as o.name + ' (' + o.desc + ')' for o in options">            
</select>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3jqV/)